# Apply An Existing Theme

Tags: theme

I have downloaded a theme from themelock.com. After unzipping the theme i have following folders: app
         skin
         js
         media.
I have merged these folders with magento main folder. In the configuration>design tab for DEFAULT CONFIGURATION, I have applied my theme under the Theme Section. Still the theme is not applicable. Do help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: clear magento cache

Comment: I have cleared the cache! my theme is applicable nw. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a highly chance that the theme also comes in a new package. Thus, you have to change the package as well:

[image]